# Writing string to file for download Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, file-io

I am building an application that makes a lot of API calls. I would like to be able to write the output of each API call to a file and then be able to download that file. So far this is what my controller looks like:

```
def show
   @resp = Faraday.get("https://my_api_endpoint")
end
```

How can I write a string to a file and download that file with Ruby on Rails?

Comment: How big is the response? Do you want to download the response only once or multiple times? Do you need to ensure that only the user requesting the API request is allowed to download the file later on? How does your server setup look like, are you able to store the file in the local file system, or do you need to store it at another location (e.g. S3 etc)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is too vague.

You can  write to file this way:

```
File.write(Rails.root.join("PATH_TO_FILE.txt"), @resp.to_s, mode: "a")
```

But you should attach a file to your model to be able to retrieve it later e.g.

`has_one_attached :response_txt`